# Is there a way to (i) automatically refresh a url and (2) scroll-down to the end?

Tags: google-chrome, url, google-chrome-extension, automation, refresh

My ideal goal is a modified version of [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-auto-scrolldown/aegbbdpcnbnddiipcggakoglcmlgejem?hl=en)

I want to keep a window always open on a website, and that window is supposed to refresh and bring me at the bottom of the page, continuously (until I stop/close). How do you suggest to proceed?

I found extensions for auto-refresh and extensions for auto-scrolldown, but nothing that puts them together

Comment: Have you tried to make a Web-Extension yourself yet? First make a hello world. And then inject a content script. That scrolls down for example with window.scrollTo(). Then make a background script that refresh the page...